# Android Update Statement

Tags: android, sqlite

Im using a simple function that receives to parameters (a String and an int). The table contains two rows, one a name and the second a value. I would like to update the row matching the string passed in with a new value (Current value - int passed in).

What I have at the moment is  below, when I run I get no errors but the results arent changing. I am just wondering if

**Query**

```
public boolean deductIngredient(String ingredient, int measurement)
{
    db.rawQuery("update kitchen set measurement = measurement - "+measurement+" where kitchen.ingredient_name = " + "'"+ingredient+"'", null);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `db.update()`?

Comment: Just used raw.Query first, hadnt thought about `.update()` is the query I posted correct thought?

Comment: The query is fine, but you need to use execSQL instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any database operation other than `SELECT`, you need to use [`execSQL()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)), not `rawQuery()`, so something like the following would work:

```
public boolean deductIngredient(String ingredient, int measurement) {
    db.execSQL( "update kitchen set measurement = measurement - ? where kitchen.ingredient_name = ?", new Object[] { Integer.valueOf( measurement ), ingredient } );
    return true;
}
```